Distorted Arm Mesh
Good Morning,
I've been having an issue where no matter what I try, the arm segment is always distorted in UE5. I am currently using Game Rig Tools along with Voxel Diffuse Skinning and Import to Unreal.
I have tried the following:

Auto Apply Weights + Voxel Diffuse
Cleared overlapping vertices
Disconnect Mesh from hand (see if hand mesh is influencing arm)
Recreated arms mesh
Clear all weights, reset pose (Alt+G/R/S), "Apply pose as rest pose"
Clear additional bones from arm,(There were "Twist" bones in the upper and lower arm)
Hand paint weights (Multiple times before trying Voxel Diffuse Skinning

I've spent a good several days attempting to fix this, and this is my first attempt at character creation and rigging. Any insight would greatly be appreciated, I feel it's something simple that I'm unaware of.




Hello and welcome. Please share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com
